# Is C-7 chord associated with one of the three minor scales?

Tags: theory, scales, jazz

I'm writing questions on index cards to help me study music theory.  Some of the questions I make up, including this one: "What minor scale is the jazz chord `C–7` associated with?"

I believe the answer is: the Dorian mode of `C` major.  Hence, there is no minor scale associated with it.  So I'm posting here to confirm that this is correct.

Is it true that a minor chord isn't always associated with one of the three typical minor scales (namely: natural minor, harmonic minor or melodic minor)?

Comment: Doesn't the Dorian mode of C major contain all the notes of C major? Usually called D Dorian. Maybe it should be the Dorian mode of Bb?  It's the thorny one of C Dorian is *not* the same as the Dorian *of* C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your question, in almost all cases involving traditional jazz harmony, a minor chord *will* be associated with one of the minor scales. However, there are four (not three) minor scales, and dorian is generally considered to be one of them. The four types are:

- dorian minor
- aeolian minor
- melodic minor
- harmonic minor

You'll notice natural minor isn't in the list. That's because aeolian minor and natural minor are identical (they both use a ♭6 and a ♭7).

The chord `Cmin7` or `C–7` does not definitively pair with any one minor scale. When you see this chord, here are the candidate minor scales:

- `C` dorian minor
- `C` aeolian minor

`C` melodic minor and `C` harmonic minor are not strong candidates, because both of those scales contain a natural 7th, which would contrast with the flat 7th of `C–7`. To determine which of the two viable candidates to use (dorian or aeolian), look at the key of the song or at the neighboring chords. For example, if the `C–7` chord is contained in this progression:

`|  C–7  |  F7  |  BbMaj  |  BbMaj  |`

then `C` dorian minor would be more appropriate than `C` aeolian. The progression above is a ii-V-I in `BbMaj`, and it's possible to play over this entire progression *only* using modes of `BbMaj`. (In particular, you would play `C` dorian minor, then `F` mixolydian, and then `Bb` ionian.) It would be unconventional to play `C` aeolian minor in this progression, because the `Ab` contained in `C` aeolian would likely clash with the `A♮` you would in `F` mixolydian.

By contrast, consider the tune All the Things you Are, which contains this progression:

`|  C–7  |  F–7  |  Bb7  |  EbMaj7  |`

Here, it is more conventional to play `C` aeolian than `C` dorian over the first measure. The reason is that the `C–7` is leading to `F–7`, which contains an `Ab`. `C` aeolian also contains an `Ab`, and so it will lead nicely into the second measure.

To summarize, there are four types of minor scales, and only two of them would be natural choices for a `C–7` chord. Determining which of the two candidates requires an evaluation of surrounding chords and/or the key signature. These two things will tend to favor one of the candidate scales over the other. So the answer to your flashcard question is this: "the jazz chord `C–7` is associated with either `C` dorian minor or `C` aeolian/natural minor."

Comment: What about Phrygian? With a minor third doesn't it qualify at all? In some sequences, most if not all the notes would work, wouldn't they? +1 again!